# How do you keep the currently selected option on an account page after reloading?

Tags: php

I have a website where you can select a background for your profile so everyone can see it.

The code I have is:

```
  <li>
      Background:<br />
      <select name="bg">
          <option value="css/halloween.gif">None</option>
          <option value="http://images2.layoutsparks.com/1/165464/baby-dragon-purple-lightning.jpg">Purple Lightning</option>
          <option value="http://c.editingmyspace.com/files/en/backgrounds/valentines.day.backgrounds/valentines_day_background_032.jpg">Valentines</option>
      </select>
  </li>
```

I know how to post it but I need it too stay the currently selected on. How would I do this?

Comment: You need to loop over the available options and match the user's preference.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more and provide any example of what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can store the selected background for the user in a database when the selection changes and retrieve it when the user logs in. To keep the background during a login-session, you should store the value in a session or a cookie and delete the cookie when the user logs off.

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at [PHP sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php).